# How to configure sequences of commands on Texmaker?

Tags: compiling, texmaker

In the bar of compilation options there are open options marked 1, 2, 3...

[image]

I know it is possible to configure sequences of commands and attribute then to these numbers because I`ve done so in my older computer, following instructions I found, but which I could not find again this time.

What I want to do is to set number 1 to latex->dvips->ps2pdf.

Can you help me do so?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Go to `User > User Commands > Edit User Commands`

There you find on the right side a button called `wizard`
[image]

Opening the wizard you can easily set your own commands
[image]

After you saved your command you can call it from the dropdown menu or go to `User > User Commands` and select your command.

Or you can even use the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for command 1, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> for command 2, and so on